# Hibernate IN clause from a JSONArray

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying get a list with Hibernate. I get a JSONArray with the IN values. 
`JSONArray rolesEnSession` is, for example, `["ROLE1", "ROLE2"]`

```
public List<MenuLeft> getMenu(JSONArray rolesEnSession){


        String listaRoles = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < rolesEnSession.length(); i++) {
            try {
                listaRoles =  listaRoles + "'"+rolesEnSession.getString(i)+",";
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LinkDAOImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("from MenuLeft "
                        + "WHERE menuRol in (:rolesEnSession)")
                .setParameter("rolesEnSession", listaRoles)
                .list();
    }
```

But I get a blank value. The column menuRol in database has values `ROLE1` and `ROLE2`

Answer (score 0):

Consider `listaRoles` after two iterations with your current code. It will have value:

`'ROLE_1,'ROLE_2,`

Instead of trying to build a well-formed string of parameter values, just change `listaRoles` to be an actual `List` and pass that in as a parameter. Let Hibernate handle the conversion to a valid SQL.

Comment: How can I do it? Only `List listaRoles = (List) rolesEnSession;`  ??

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13172820/69352) answer

Comment: I try it but I get
`java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: @GiancarloVenturaGranados can you show me your code?

Comment: The code above it is the code. What code do you want to show you?

Comment: You tried "it". Presumably you now have code that is attempting to cast a list to a string? I'd like to see that code

Comment: I try everyone. I realize the query without parameters and it results. :/